# Managing visibly different sizes of multiple fonts being used

Tags: html, css, web

I am using 2 very different fonts in a responsive website. The complication is that the 2 fonts look quite different at the same exact size. So I need some way or another to alter the typography rules based on the font-family. I can always use a class wherever I'm using the secondary font and manage the sizing, but suddenly I'll have to duplicate the responsive typography rules.

Is there any easier way to do this? related to some certain font-* attribute that scales the rendered font-height, or a font-family based selector?

Answer (score 0):

When you declare your font to an element, you could simply add your font-size.

```
.navigation p {
   font-family: 'A';
   font-size: 1em;
}

p {
   font-family: 'B';
   font-size:1.2em;
}
```

Because you can only use one font per text, there is no need for a font-family selector.

Comment: There's a whole responsive typography in the css. If I go this way, I'll have to replicate the size typography for this hierarchy of classes as well. This solution would have been worked nicely if the whole site was sized relatively (using em), but unfortunately I'm working on an existing theme designed by designers who are very kin on having everything pixel perfect.